# Image draw issue on Linux using Xlib

Tags: c++, linux, jpeg, xlib

I am developing an application, in which I am receiving images from my window host.. the client side is in Linux using C++.. I am sending JPEG format from server side.. the problem I am facing is that when I receive the image on client, I use "XCreateImage" function to create the "XImage" and when I write this image to a file, it appears to be perfect.. but when I pass this image to "XPutImage" the image is not displayed properly... lot of noise in image... Why it is so? any idea? or any test code? Please help me out..

Comment: It's done... there was error in XCreateImage..

Comment: Perhaps close your own question then? :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an error in XCreateImage. If you fix that then your program should work fine.

But why, WHY are you using Xlib all by itself? That's self-flagellation, although some might consider it spiritually beneficial there are many better options that abstract away much of that arcane Xlib garbage.